# How to use 'depth'?

Tags: php

I wanna use 'depth' in a sidebar menu to only display the first child page, and I wonder where in my code I should insert depth?
I wanna be able to only show the first child page and not all child pages. 
I have tried to insert 'depth' under this if conditon

```
if ( $item->current_item_ancestor && $item->menu_item_parent == '0' )
{
    $last_parent = $item,
    'depth' => 1
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------- */

function myproject_nav_menu_objects_start_in( $sorted_menu_items, $args )
{

   switch ( $args->menu_id )
   {
       case 'sidebar-menu' :

       $current = false;
       $last_parent = false;
       $menu = array();

       foreach( $sorted_menu_items as $item )
       {
           if ( $item->current_item_ancestor && $item->menu_item_parent == '0' )
               $last_parent = $item;

           if ( $item->current )
               $current = $item;
       }

       if ( $current ) 
       {
           $keys = array();
           $last_parent = ( ! $last_parent ) ? $current : $last_parent;

           $children = _myproject_submenu_get_children_ids( $last_parent->ID, $sorted_menu_items );

           foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $key => $item ) 
           {
               if ( ! in_array( $item->ID, $children ) )
                   unset( $sorted_menu_items[$key] );
           }

       }
       else
       {
           $sorted_menu_items = array();
       }

       break;

   }
   return $sorted_menu_items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'myproject_nav_menu_objects_start_in', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

On recursive methods, I usually add a `$depth` parameter:

```
function my_function($depth = -1)
{
    if ($depth === 0) {
        return array(); // or any other value insisting an empty or false result
    }
    // do something
    $result = array();
    while ($some_condition) {
        $result = array_merge($result, my_function($depth - 1)); // decrease $depth value
    }
    // maybe do something more
    return $result;
}
```

When calling my_function() without a `$depth` parameter, there won't be any restriction in the depth. But if you provide a `$depth` value, it'll stop recursion when the `$depth` value is zero.

Don't use `$depth--` in a loop. `$depth - 1` is the correct way.

Comment: Ok, Im gonna test your code a little bit.